# Is str("str") always an identity function?

Tags: python, string, string-interning

<s>So simple question here:</s>

I see for certain objects that a call to `str` can actually create a new object reference

```
>>> a = 1
>>> str(a) is str(a)
False
```

However, I notice that this is not true for strings (which seems intuitive). Does the `str` method always act as an identity function for `str` objects? Or does this property just seem correct due to string interning optimizations, and may not actually return the same reference?

```
>>> a = "1"
>>> a is str(a)
True
>>> str(a) is str(a)
True
```

Is this a global rule/ language specification rule, or is it going to be interpreter dependent?

FWIW I'm asking this question because in a few places I safeguard some methods to ensure a `str` instance is used. I wanted to know if I'm creating garbage by adding the redundant `str` call around inputs which are already type `str`. e.g.

```
def safeguard_foo(val):
    foo(str(val))
```

Another option is to safeguard in a more verbose fashion (it's worth noting that this method is about 25% faster anyways, so in terms of performance it wins out even before considering the garbage creation concerns). e.g.

```
def safeguard_foo(val):
    if not isinstance(val, str):
        val = str(val)
    foo(val)
```

Comment: Are you asking about whether something is true in a given interpreter release, or whether it's guaranteed to be true in *any* interpreter implementing the Python language specification? (If a hypothetical non-CPython interpreter had a different implementation, but did not conflict with any part of the Python language specification, would you consider that to invalidate an answer that said that `str(somestr)` would always return the object it was passed?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Specifically I have some code safeguarding that `str` is passed, I'm interested to know if I'm creating garbage by adding the redundant `str` call around objects which are already strings

Comment: Gotcha! Pretty sure you're not, in CPython, but I don't *think* that's a language-spec guarantee. Will need to dig in when I have a minute, if someone else hasn't done likewise first.

Comment: Quick note for anyone else doing said digging: `PyTypeObject.tp_str` is a good place to start. `Objects/object.c`'s implementation of `PyObject_Str`, likewise. I'm less convinced than I used to be that there will never be GC load created by a redundant `str()` call, but can't as yet prove it either way.

Comment: Don't worry about this unless it's actually causing a performance problem. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Even if it's not optimized, most of the time the difference is negligible. Write it in the way that's most clear to the reader, worry about performance later if necessary.

Comment: In https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str, second paragraph, doesn't _"For string objects, this is the string itself."_ means that it is identity operation? I would interpret this confusing sentence as "yes", it is identity operation.

Comment: If your goal is to "safeguard some methods to ensure a `str` instance is used" why not use `isinstance(val, str)`?

Comment: @Adam In my experience, `isinstance()` is a very slow operation. I try to avoid it as much as I can due to performance issues.

Comment: @AGNGazer are you sure? I just tried with `timeit` and `isinstance` is 4x faster than your `str() == str()` construction.

Comment: @Adam It looks like things have changed since I last did this check. And so you are right.

Comment: @flakes Performance-wise `isinstance()` seems to be more performance than `str()`. However, if most of the time input is of non-string type, then having to run `isinstance` first and then `str()` would be a less performant option. If most of the time you expect input already be a string and only occasionally a non-string, then I would use `isinstance`

Comment: That's right `isinstance` is faster when `a` is a string, and `str(a)` is faster when it isn't. But the difference is tiny, and @Barmar is right that this is premature optimization. If this difference matters then this is in your inner loops, which means you have much bigger design problems. Use `str(a)` and spend your profiling time where it actually matters.

Comment: Also, even a faster option, probably is to have something like this: `def sure_str(x): try: return x+'' except TypeError: return str(x)` (insert line breaks as needed)

Comment: @norok2 made a valid point that `try-except` is not safe.

Comment: @flakes I'd actually be more wary of objects that would not `str()` *nicely* *, e.g. without going too far `str(b'ciao') == "b'ciao'"`. *whatever that may mean
`